# Как отобразить скачанное изображение vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Сервер:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
    try (InputStream is = fileStorageService.get(image); OutputStream rsp = response.getOutputStream()) {
        IOUtils.copy(is, rsp);
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
```

На фронте скачиваю картинку в переменную item.image, каким образом ее можно отобразить?

```
v-bind:src="item.image"
```

не помогает

Comment: А `item.image` это что? src путь требует к файлу.

Comment: @AlexSazonov переменная в которую скачал картинку

Comment: Что значит "скачал картинку"? Сделайте `console.log(item.image)`. Что покажет?

Answer (score 0):

Работает с `<img src="host/getImage?image=C:/1.jpg"/>`

Comment: А что ответит сервер на `<img src="host/getImage?image=C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"/>` ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ понял, спасибо)

Comment: Нет проблем, лишь бы помогло